# Which user (www-data or vagrant) runs Laravel app in Homestead virtual server?

Tags: linux, nginx

My laravel application in the production server can save file to the mounted directory below:

```
drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data       posts
```

On the other hand, permission error occurs for the same operation (same remote directory) in Homestead.

When a Laravel application runs in virtual Homestead, which user (vagrant or www-data) is active? Is it different than production server?